# A conjecture about an equilateral triangle bound to any triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

First, I would like to show where I want to go...

[image]

... because I find this picture beautiful.

Now, consider any triangle $ABD$, and build an equilateral triangle $ABC$ on one of its longest sides.[image]

Let draw two circles, the first passing by $B$,  $C$, $D$ and the second with center in $A$ and passing by $D$ (i.e. with center on the opposite vertex with respect to the side $BC$).

[image]

These two circles determine a point $P$, in correspondence of their (other) intersection.

Let us do the same for the other two sides, obtaining other two points $N$ and $O$.

[image]

> **My conjecture is that the triangle $ONP$ is always equilateral.**

[image]

Although it is likely and obvious/known result, my question is

> **Is there an elementary proof for such conjecture?**

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true. It has little to do with the original triangle. What you're doing is to reflect the point $D$ in each of the three angle bisectors of an equilateral triangle. The resulting points form an equilateral triangle because the product of any two of these reflections is a rotation through $\frac{2\pi}3$ around the centre of the triangle.

Comment: I see. But this remains true also when the point $D$ is _outside_ the equilateral triangle used for the construction. But, of course, it may be obvious.

Comment: @andrea.prunotto: I don't see where I assumed that $D$ is inside the triangle.

Comment: Yep, got it! Ignore my comment. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: But I disagree with the fact that this has little to do with the original triangle, because the area of the obtained equilateral triangle strongly depends on the position of $D$ with respect to $AB$, i.e. on the shape of the original triangle, don't you think?

Comment: @andrea.prunotto: Yes, if you're interested in the area, that certainly has to do with the original triangle. I was just focused on the fact you were trying to prove, that the resulting triangle is equilateral; I meant that that's just a fact about $D$ and $\Delta ABC$, and where they came from doesn't figure in the proof.

Comment: I understand... Is this related to the fact that $D$ must lie on the circle passing by $O$, $N$ and $P$?

Comment: @andrea.prunotto: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that -- I just didn't use the original triangle in the proof; I'm not sure what it would mean for something to be related to that. $D$ does lie on that circle, because the reflections in the angle bisectors preserve the distance from the centre.

Comment: Yes! Now I see it! Thanks for your clarifications!